# Liquid - how to view all data in an object?

Tags: liquid, eleventy

I am iterating around an object in Liquid for an Eleventy website, how can I see the full contents of that object?

for example

```
  {%- for post in collections.posts -%}
    <li>{{ post.data.date }}</>
  {%- endfor -%}
```

shows me a list of dates.

I would like to do something like this to discover every different element of the object.  Is this possible?

```
<li>{{ post.data[0] }}</>
```

Currently it shows nothing but if I write `post`, it outputs `object object`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you can use `log` to do this.

```
<li>{{ post.data | log }}</li>
```

Also, I think you can do this if you want to view the contents of a specific post:

```
<li>{{ post.0.data | log }}</li>
```